# Растянуть linear-gradient на весь body

Tags: html, css3

Как можно сделать такой фон, чтобы он не повторялся, а был растянут на всю страницу?

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(40, 40, 40), rgb(50, 50, 50));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Убрать повторение для фона, а для `body` и `html` задать высоту 100%:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(40, 40, 40), rgb(50, 50, 50)) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! А можете объяснить, почему надо так делать?

Comment: @Юрий, По-умолчанию высота `body` равна высоте контента внутри него, поэтому мы задаем ему высоту 100% чтобы растянуть его на всю страницу. А чтобы `body` задать высоту 100%, нужно чтобы и у родителя была высота 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Почему-то не работает с `height: 100%`, пришлось сделать так:

```
html,
body {
  height: max-content;
}
```